# Security in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, security, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm new to the world of coffeescript (javascript). Currently building my first backbone.js app which communicates with a Rails backend over SSL.

Over the years I've been told many times over that *"JavaScript security sucks, so perform all logic server-side if possible."* I've got a handle on server-side security, but what about the client?

It's possible that some of my backbone models will contain information that users will wish to protect.

**Update 1**: In response to @Nupul, I wish to protect tuples of `(integer, string, datetime)`. Nothing that could compromise any remote system.

**Update 2**: So the only thing to be aware of is to provide the same data to backbone that one would consider secure to provide in a js-free html view?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you wish to protect in the first place...data in the models is just variable data/content that is manipulated on client side...what you transmit will probably be over SSL so I'm not sure what do you really want to protect? Try encrypting everything in the models if that's much of a concern but you'll quickly realize it to be an overkill, low on performance and probably not worth it :)

Comment: @Alex: re: **Update 2**: Yes, that's right.

Comment: "JavaScript security sucks" statement is lame. A language does not make anything secure or insecure.

Comment: @rFactor As that may be, I'm posting here because I've heard that sentiment many times over. It is not my own. If you have something more to add, I'd be grateful for your opinion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JavaScript security, in the sense you mean, doesn't just suck, it's literally impossible. You *cannot* trust code you run on the client. You'll need to structure your program in such a way that your server never sends information to a client's computer unless you want them to be able to see it.

Comment: For a malicious user to see data in the user's model on SSL he/she must be sitting "on" the user's machine staring at the page, be adept at reading minified javascript and debugging to peek into the contents and know backbone.js

Comment: @Alex: On a serious note, what is it that you want to protect?

Comment: Yes, @jeremybanks is absolutely right here, "You cannot trust code you run on the client" always should implement security checks on server-side without even thinking that you have security checks on client-side totally ignore those checks.